# How to create a list for a function in R to auto-check-for & download multiple packages?

Tags: r

I have a script for determining whether or not a package is already installed and if not installing it:

```
if("abc" %in% rownames(installed.packages())==FALSE) {install.packages("abc")}
```

I would like to extend the single check to a list of packages, e.g. ls("abc", "MCMCpack", "BMA", "coda"), so that I can simply use the one function and edit the list at my leisure. But I need the list to be checked by the function one at a time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can use something like this...

```
check.package <- function(package){
  if(!package %in% .packages(all = TRUE)){
    cat("Package", package, "is not installed. Installing ", package, "...\n")
    install.packages(package)
    library(package)
  }
  else{
    cat("Package", package, "is already installed.\n")
  }
}
```

Example

```
> check.package("strucchange")
Package strucchange is already installed.

> check.package("midasr")
Installing package into ‘/home/aaaa/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
.....
```

Checking a list of packages:

```
> invisible(sapply(list("midasr", "strucchange"), check.package))
Package midasr is already installed. 
Package strucchange is already installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry if you're actually talking about a `list` object, i'm unclear on the desired behavior..  but do you want something like this?

```
check.install.packs <- 
    function( ps ){
        if( any( ti <- !( ps %in% installed.packages() ) ) ) 
            install.packages( ps[ ti ] )
    }
```

and then

```
check.packs( c( 'survey' , 'MonetDB.R' ) )
```

and then

```
check.packs( c( 'survey' , 'SAScii' ) )
```